# Ubuntu 22.04 unable to boot to desktop, stuck at command-line login screen

Tags: boot, desktop-environments, login-screen, gdm, initramfs

Ubuntu 22.04 unable to boot to desktop, stuck at command-line login screen after I ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`
and `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

It only shows login terminal login screen in black.
I have to manually login and run `sudo service gdm start` to get to the desktop

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

run `systemctl set-default graphical.target` and solved it